# Laravel unit tests - controller method

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5

I want your help about a testing class, i have some test method that failed in those two methods, here where it fails:

```
    class PhotoControllerTest extends TestCase

{
public function testUpdate()
    {
        $photo=$this->json('POST', '/photo', ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'photoExample']);
        $this->json('PUT','/photo/1',['id' => 1,'name' => 'photo2') ->seeJson(['success' => true,'photo'=>true] );

    }
 public function testDestroy()
    {
        $photo =$this->json('POST', '/photo', ['id' => 2,'name' => 'photo');
        $this->json('DELETE', '/photo/2') ->seeJson(['success'=>true]);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to test an update method, by storing a photo, and then trying to update it, same thing with destroy methos, any idea please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You are missing few brackets there, in both test methods, third argument of "$this->json()"... Is that only a typo in question?
Moreover with what messages are tests failing?

Comment: @IvoHrádek Thanks for your reply! For the error is "Unable to find JSON fragment ["success":true] within [{"errors":"Not found","status":"error"}].
Failed asserting that false is true." even if it should success... for the brackets it's not a typo in question, where I should put them please ?

Comment: $this->json(..., ...., ['id' => ..., 'name' => ...]); you are missing a closing array bracket.

Comment: Anyway I don't think that's issue... It's more likely that POST calling was not successful, so seeJson() failed. For unit testing I'd recommend you to put dummy data in testing database before test. You can use @before for this purpose.